# Menu option is not responding in the Stack Overflow talent - blog page in the mobile view

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, stack-overflow-talent

When navigating to the [Stack Overflow Talent - BLOG](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/blog) option in the mobile view, after when I click the menu option [image: Menu] in the right hand side top, it is not responding.

So I need to click the Stack Overflow Talent title to navigate to the initial page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. The menu has been fixed in the mobile view (it was fixed a while back, but we missed updating the status here -- sorry about that).

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem and, quite randomly, just had to clear my cookies and my cache, this solved my problem. Also try updating your browser.